# Autofac list all sub-dependencies chain registration

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Inherited a big, old, evolving C# solution and wanted to clean the Autofact IoC setup.

Is there a quick way (or piece of code) that can tell me what classes are used where (hierarchical tree)?

In the project, the ContainerBuilder calls to Register, RegisterType, RegisterInstance, RegisterApiControllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this [is the same as the answer to this somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381300/enumerating-disposables-tracked-by-an-autofac-lifetime/39396968#39396968) about tracking disposables in Autofac.

The short version: Analytics is one of the weak spots in Autofac and we're looking to improve. You can try hacking something together on your own using the various [lifetime events available](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/events.html) but there's nothing built in. You may want to look at the [autofac-analysis repo](https://github.com/autofac/autofac-analysis) for ideas. We do have an [open feature request](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/788) for something more visual.

Unfortunately, that's the best we can offer at the moment.

If you come up with something cool or have specific ideas for places where we can add hooks for easier analytics integration, [file an issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues) and we can talk about how things should work.